# how do i ignore a an integer in this string string

Tags: ios, swift

i have this recorded tap in swift to go to the next page:
 XCUIApplication().scrollViews.otherElements.tables.collectionViews.staticTexts["Baked Goods (23)-0-BrandCardCell-titleLabel"].tap()

how do you write a NSPredicate that will ignore the (23) because that number will change from time to time and still allow me to tap to the next page

thanks in advance

Comment: Use [regEx](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression).

Answer (score -2):

It isn't clear what you mean by

> i have this recorded tap in swift to go to the next page:
>   XCUIApplication().scrollViews.otherElements.tables.collectionViews.staticTexts["Baked
>   Goods (23)-0-BrandCardCell-titleLabel"].tap()

How are you recording taps, and what are you doing with them?

As for how to parse your string, shallowThought told you the answer. You need to create a regular expression. Take a look at this link, which has a Swift example of creating an NSPredicate that uses regular expressions